lwc spinner does not stop in salesforce screen flow
I've integrated my custom lwc spinner to the screen flow. It just basically shows spinner if the boolean variable is true.
I've called the lwc from my flow, given the boolean input. After my Apex call completed, I want it to stop spinning, so I've changed the boolean variable to false but it does not stop. You can see the part of the Flow where I'm trying to implement this logic.


In Show spinner -> I've set the boolean variable to True
In Loading    screen -> I've called my lwc with the boolean variable
In Do not show spinner -> I've set the boolean variable to False


What logic moves the user on from the loading screen? Does your flow actually proceed to the next step, or does it end up stuck on the loading screen?

yeah looks like it stuck on the loading screen, but I do not want users to proceed by themselves, it should continue automatically

Unfortunately that's not how the current set up would work. If you want that, you need to incorporate the Apex Action in your LWC, which would then have to programmatically navigate the user to the next step in the Flow. As it stands, the user will get to the Loading Screen Node, and then the Apex Action will never be called because the Flow doesn't proceed past the Loading Screen.

Absolutely, I've integrated my Apex logic into the LWC, then control the spinner based on the method results. Thank you so much @CallumMacErlich.
